# Percent of Hidden Values in PivotTable? Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a Percent of Parent Column field that works fine.  But in the axis of values, I only want one shown to make the table much more compact.  Essentially imagine if you had a table showing the percent of different animal types in various water bodies.  You had Mammals, Fish, Reptiles, etc. I have several other dimensions involved in the pivot tables, so the Percent of Parent Column is the one that always gives the correct value.

However, I only want to display the percentage for Mammals.  So I filtered the animal types down to just mammals.  Great, except now the percentage is only a percent of what is shown, meaning it is always 100%, since there are no other animal types displayed.

In Access there used to be a way to include hidden values when calculating percentages which is similar to what I need in Excel, but no such option have I been able to find in Excel.  Any suggestions?

Comment: eggsactly the same q here!

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just hide the actual Excel columns (or rows) to achieve this appearance?

Comment: Only works if the pivot table is static.  Since you can change filters/slicers on a pivot table, then the column, such as G, is not always something I would want hidden.